# Complex C# class returned by API service doesn't serialize correctly

Tags: c#, rest, api, blazor-server-side

While working on a simple Blazor POC I came through a problem I can’t solve, so I hope someone out there may help me
getting it right .
Ok , let’s explain step by step. In VS2019, I created next solution:

[image]

•   WebClient: Is a Blazor server side App holding the UI and presentation logic.

•   Domain: Is a .NET Standard 2.1 holding the domain logic for a Vending machine.

•   Api : Is used to retrieve and persist the state of a Vending machine.

[image]

In Domain project, the 2 classes of interest are the MyVendingMachine class (which is an entity)
And Money class (which is a value object).
So knowing this, let’s first explain the use case of the simple POC project, this by showing the
corresponding UI:

[image]

So when starting up a simple screen is showing and the user can enter some money (limited to either
5€-10€-20€-50€ euro banknotes). When user enters money, “Money inserted” shows the amount of
Money the user entered and the user can next “Buy a snack” which will add the entered amount to
the vending machine. 
For example, user enters 5€, UI will update as next:

[image]

next clicks the “Buy snack” button, then UI will update as next:

[image]

There is also another use-case “Return money” which returns entered money to the customer.
This all works fine. But another use-case of the POC is to persist and load the current state of
The vending machine from storage through an API. This API is quit simple and returns a
manually instance of a vending machine and 50€ of initial money inside from the API controller,
as next:

[image]

So quit simple, when the API endpoint get’s git we create a vending machine,
double the request id (just to test this comes from api) and add 50€ as initial
state for the money inside. When we test this request in Postman, we get next in response:

[image]

But, when called from my api service class (which is part of the web app project I get next):
[image]

The Id is correct (so we know it got deserizalized from the API), but the MoneyInside has not been serialized correctly with the value obtained from the API (50€)
So FiftyEuroCount in this case should be set to 1, which isn’t (value:  0).
Any clue ?
For completeness, the MyVendingMachine and Money classes:

[image]

[image]

Kr,
Emmanuel Nuyttens.

Comment: would be intresting to see if you changed the prop "Amount" to "amount", does it work then? maybe propertyNameCaseInsensitive does not work on complex objects? 
I can recommend [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to handle json, you handle the properties name by either defining a [strategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) or an [attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) on the props them selfs. Heres how u [serialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) // deserialize

Comment: Hi Truckarn, thx for the tip but this didn't workout either. For a guess i also changed the MoneyInside into moneyInside but this didn't help either.